# How to use CanCanCan with enum field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, authorization, cancancan

I got **Article** model with enum field `enum status: [:pending, :done]`.

Here's my ability file

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new

    if user.member?
      can :read, Article.done
    end
  end
end
```

In view I am trying to render **Article.done** collection for member but nothings renders.

```
<% if can? :read, Article.done %> 
  <%= render partial: 'article', collection: Article.done, as: :article %>
<% end %>
```

Therefore I have a question: is there any possible way to work with enum in CanCanCan?

Comment: From my experience, `enum` doesn't create any `class methods` (which you're using here)

Comment: @RichPeck At least in Rails 4 it actually does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be wrong, <s>but I think that `enum` only creates `instance` methods:</s>.

```
@article = Article.find params[:id]
@article.done?
```

[I *was* wrong](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)...

> Scopes based on the allowed values of the enum field will be provided
>   as well. With the above example:
>
> ```
> Conversation.active
> Conversation.archived
> ```

--

I'll delete this if it doesn't work; I would be evaluating against the [hash of conditions](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/defining-abilities#hash-of-conditions), not the class itself:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new

    if user.member?
      can :read, Article, status: Article.statuses[:done]
    end
  end
end
```

---

**Update**

Several important things to consider.

Firstly, when using `hash` conditions:

> Important: If a block or hash of conditions exist they will be ignored when checking on a class, and it will return true.

This means that you cannot call specific conditions on an "ability" whilst passing a class, it has to be called on an instance of an object.

Secondly, it seems [CanCanCan has some issues evaluating `enum` values](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/issues/102), which makes the following code necessary:

```
#app/models/ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    if user.member?
      can :read, Article do |article|
        article.done?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You then need to pass the `article` instance to the `can?` method:

```
#app/views/articles/index.html.erb
<table>
    <%= render @articles %>
</table>

#app/views/articles/_article.html.erb
<% if can? :read, article %>
    <tr>
      <td>Title:</td>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.status %></td>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Unfortunately It didn't work out, but I appreciate your trying to help.

Comment: Any feedback? What happened? What responses did you get? You can't give up that easily

Comment: So the problem still exists, the collection doesn't render. I feel like probably I  somehow should bypass using class definitions.

Comment: Hmm, what if you go into your rails console (`rails c`) and then type `Article.done` to see what it comes back with? Maybe the collection just doesn't exist?

Comment: Thank God I'm not that dumb. If I remove **if statement** the collection shows up.

Comment: This means the collection exists. Are you sure your `user` is a `member`?

Comment: Okay. why don't you try `if user.member? can :read, Article` to see if that shows collection?

Comment: In that case collection is being displayed flawlessly.

Comment: Okay so it means our check is false. What about using `can :read, Article, status: 1`

Comment: In this case, when I checking in my view with `- if can? :read, Article` the collection is present, however the whole collection. I mean enum scope doesn't apply

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101467/discussion-between-rich-peck-and-alexander-shmatko).

Comment: Check out chat room.

Comment: Updated as per discussion & solution - this should be accepted as it's confirmed as working by both parties

Comment: is there a support now for enums directly? Can we do something like  
 if user.member?  can :read, status => :published without using a block and passing article?

Comment: No because you have to evaluate the instance of the class, not the class itself